# haproxy return empty response

Tags: haproxy, health-monitoring

I'd like to have health checks to an haproxy instance fail solely based on whether haproxy is running. In other words I don't want the health check to be proxied to a backend server.

I see there is a way to do this by [returning a static file](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/how-do-i-serve-a-single-static-file-from-haproxy/32). This would work for me, but I was wondering: Is there a way to return an empty response with just a status code without having to return a file and deal with the false 503? The solution linked seems hacky and I worry that behavior will not be allowed in some later version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> monitor-uri <uri>
>
> Intercept a URI used by external components' monitor requests
> May be used in sections :
> ```
>
> When an HTTP request referencing  will be received on a frontend,
>   HAProxy will not forward it nor log it, but instead will return either
>   "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" or "HTTP/1.0 503 Service unavailable", depending on
>   failure conditions defined with "monitor fail". This is normally
>   enough for any front-end HTTP probe to detect that the service is UP
>   and running without forwarding the request to a backend server. Note
>   that the HTTP method, the version and all headers are ignored, but the
>   request must at least be valid at the HTTP level. This keyword may
>   only be used with an HTTP-mode frontend.
>
> ## Example :
>
> ```
> # Use /haproxy_test to report haproxy's status
> frontend www
>     mode http
>     monitor-uri /haproxy_test
> ```